# pycurl install looks for a non-existent file (libcurl.a)

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I'm running a Gentoo Linux system under which I've never had problems installing anything into my virtualenv using `pip`.  I've managed installing PIL and django, but for some reason, `pycurl` (a dependency of `cloudkey`) is flipping out, claiming that I don't have `libcurl.a` (note that it's not `.la`) on my system.

`curl` is installed.  In fact, pycurl is installed on the host system just fine, but it just won't install into my virtualenv.  Here's the output:

```
$ pip install cloudkey
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cloudkey in /path/to/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): distribute in /path/to/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from cloudkey)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): simplejson>=2.0.9 in /path/to/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from cloudkey)
Downloading/unpacking pycurl>=7.19.0 (from cloudkey)
  Downloading pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz (71Kb): 71Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pycurl
Using curl-config (libcurl 7.23.1)
Installing collected packages: pycurl
  Running setup.py install for pycurl
Using curl-config (libcurl 7.23.1)
building 'pycurl' extension
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fPIC -DHAVE_CURL_OPENSSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_OPENSSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_OPENSSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_OPENSSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c src/pycurl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/src/pycurl.o
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/src/pycurl.o -L/usr/lib64 -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -lldap -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lssl -lcrypto -lldap -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lpython2.6 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/pycurl.so /usr/lib64/libcurl.a -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc: /usr/lib64/libcurl.a: No such file or directory
error: command 'x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
Complete output from command /path/to/virtualenv/bin/python2.6 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/path/to/virtualenv/build/pycurl/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-kkwDnf-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /path/to/virtualenv/include/site/python2.6:
Using curl-config (libcurl 7.23.1)

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/curl

copying python/curl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/curl

running build_ext

building 'pycurl' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/src

x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fPIC -DHAVE_CURL_OPENSSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_OPENSSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_OPENSSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_OPENSSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c src/pycurl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/src/pycurl.o

x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/src/pycurl.o -L/usr/lib64 -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -lldap -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lssl -lcrypto -lldap -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lpython2.6 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/pycurl.so /usr/lib64/libcurl.a -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed

x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc: /usr/lib64/libcurl.a: No such file or directory

error: command 'x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /path/to/virtualenv/bin/python2.6 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/path/to/virtualenv/build/pycurl/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-kkwDnf-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /path/to/virtualenv/include/site/python2.6 failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /home/daniel/.pip/pip.log
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned you were using Gentoo, you may want to use portage to find out what package owns that file.  You can use equery (`emerge gentoolkit`) to figure out what package owns it:

```
equery belongs /usr/lib64/libcurl.a
```

Comment: That's the kooky part!  Running that command returns 0 results.  The file isn't on the filesystem and even re-emerging pycurl into the host OS doesn't make it reappear.  It's as if pycurl requires a file that isn't part of libcurl anymore.

Comment: You know, I ran the same command on Ubuntu--that file appeared in libcurl4, but not libcurl3 (which was what was installed).  I wonder if this appears in a newer version of curl?

Comment: I figured it out!  `libcurl` had to be installed with `USE="static-libs"` (not the default).  Once that was done, the aforementioned `equery` command returned a valid result and I could run `pip install pycurl` in my virtualenv.

Comment: Awesome!  Good work Daniel